# asp.net mvc / dynamicdata entities which one to try out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entities, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am going to develop a web application, the client left me with the choice of application development, I am currently doing those kind of jobs with vs2008 (.net 3.5), now I wish to develop this new app either in asp.net MVC or develop it using dynamic data entities.

I would like to use this as an opportunity to learn, any guidance  will be helpful.

Regarding the application, it is not a very big application but going to be used in multi merchandising stations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set on MVC3.

Disadvantages in my opinion about Dynamic Data Entities:

- There is not so much rumor about it in forums like SO or other... might be a indicator that nobody uses it
- I had a look at it some times ago, and I didn't like the way it can be extend and modified
- I think DD is good for small applications with no big logic (Implementing, Business Layer, Logging, Security etc might be tricky)